# WPF window modal dialog using MVVM and viewmodel communication

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern with WPF. I have a mainwindow. Mainwindow has a viewmodel. A button click on the mainwindow opens a Modal dialog.  In this Modal dialog there is a user control. This usercontrol also has a viewmodel. When I change a property in the Usercontrol, how can i make the main window aware of the change.

I do not understand the communication between the viewmodels of mainwindow and the modal dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good way of talking between ViewModel's is by the use of Messaging, a good way of implementing this is by using the MVVM Light Toolkit.

You can learn more about it [here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)

Comment: I cannot use MVVM frameworks because I have to keep the deploymen simple.

Comment: You can look at the source and take the lead of how MVVM light handles Messaging. Just on a side, why do you think MVVM Light would complicate your deployment.